# User input and while loop

Tags: python, loops, input, while-loop

I'm trying to write a Python program where it asks user to make selection using 1, 2 or 3. If user doesn't enter those, it prompts user to enter only those numbers.

Once the user enters 1, 2 or 3, the program then asks it AGAIN to enter 1, 2 or 3. This is repeated 10 times, and if user doesn't enter either 1, 2 or 3, it prompts user to enter only those numbers. This is what I have so far;

```
while(choice>3 or choice<1):
    choice = int(input("Please enter a value from 1 - 3 only:" ))
    while (((choice == 1 or choice == 2 or choice == 3) and (count < 10))):
            run program
```

Problem is that if the user initially enters 1, 2 or 3, program doesn't run. But if user enters something other than 1, 2 or 3 the first time, the program behaves like I want it to.

Comment: That's the expected behaviour. ``if choice is ǸOT 1,2,3, then skip the block else execute the block!``

Answer (score 1):

It will not run when `1,2,3` are entered because the while loop excludes those numbers.

Code:

```
while(choice>3 or choice<1):
```

`1,2, and 3` will skip this block- therefore the code inside the block will not be run, and the program will do nothing.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, I know I can make another while loop on top of my first while loop that is  while (((choice == 1 or choice == 2 or choice == 3) and (count < 10))) and get the program to do what I want but I do not want to repeat my entire code just because of this

Answer (score 1):

With code as similar as possible to what you had:

```
try_count = 0
choice = ""
valid = False

while True:
    print("Please enter a number between 1 and 3")
    while True:
        try_count += 1

        choice = input("")

        try: #make sure the user has entered a number
            choice = int(choice)
            if choice >= 1 or choice <= 3: #if the value is outside our range
                valid = True
                break #then we're done!
        except:
            continue #if the user didn't enter a number, go around again

        if try_count >= 10: #if we've done this ten times exit
            try_count = 0
            break #exit to the outer loop

        if valid: #if we've got a proper value, we're done
            break #exit the loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Blue Ice mentioned above the problem lies with this line:

```
while(choice>3 or choice<1):
```

The problem is that you are only running this while loop if the choice is greater than 3 or less than 1 but inside this loop you are testing for this condition:

```
while (((choice == 1 or choice == 2 or choice == 3) and (count < 10))):
```

This code is always unreachable becasue for the first while loop to run it requires numbers other than 1, 2, or 3 to enter the loop. This means that this while loop can never run because the first condition you are testing for is guarenteed to be false and thus you and comparison can never evaluate to true becasue `True and False is False` no matter what

Personally I would not create my input prompt in the way that you did because it is not as easy to maintain as other options. It is possible to create menus in python using dictionaries, which is the way I prefer. What you do is store the key as the choice and the value as a reference to the function you want executed. I prefer this becasue it eliminates the need to set up all the boolean tests within your loop and it makes the addition or removal of options easier.

The code to create a menu like you ask for would look something like this.

```
options = {     1 : option_1,
                2 : option_2,
                3 : option_3
}

user_input = int(raw_input("1, 2, or 3"))

#The () are required because otherwise you will get the memory address of the function and the funciton itself won't run
options[user_input]()
```

which means of course that you would have to place your code within a function (to do that the syntax looks like this)

```
def function():
    do stuff
```

Notice how in the dictionary the functions are stored without the (). This is done because without the parenthesis it is a reference to the function itself (if you do a print you will see it give you the memory address), with the parenthesis the function will execute. Then you simply call the function by adding parenthesis to the dictiorary lookup like this `options[user_input]()`

I'm sorry I don't completely understand what you are doing with the prompting after 10 times thing because you should be prompting them to correct their input every time they mess up but I believe to use this method to do what you want to do would look something like this:

```
#Count to see how many times they mess up
count = 0
#Options dictionary
options = {     1 : option_1,
                2 : option_2,
                3 : option_3
}

#I am using Python 3 BTW
print("Enter 1, 2 or 3 ")
#And I am assuming they will give good input
user_input = int(raw_input("1, 2, or 3"))
#This more closly mimics what you are doing but like I said I would avoid this so you don't have to hard code how many options you have
#while((user_input is not 1) or (user_input is not 2) or (user_input is not 3))
#try this
#It makes sure you are not out of bounds for an any number of elements
while(user_input < 0 and user_input > len(options)):
    #if you are ask for new input
    user_input = int(raw_input("1, 2, or 3"))
    #increment count
    count += 1
    #check if they messed up 10 times 
    if(count == 10):
        print("Enter 1, 2, or 3")
        #reset count so it will tell them on the next 10th time
        count = 0

#to break the while loop above you must have valid input so call the function 
options[user_input]()

#And of course you need to define you functions to do the different options
def option_1():
    do option_1 stuff

def option_2():
    do option_2 stuff

def option_3():
    do option_3 stuff
```

Again while this is very different from what you have but it is much easier to add new options this way because you only need to add a new function and add the option to the dictionary and you don't have to worry about testing for each option you have.

TL;DR: Python dictionaries are the way to go for input, don't test for each case

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this example code :

```
choices_menu = '''
Please select input menu :
Enter 1> Show latest 100 data
Enter 2> Show latest 1000 data
Enter 3> Show all data'''

choice = 0
while(choice>3 or choice<1):
    print choices_menu
    choice = raw_input("Your choice (Input number 1 to 3) ? ")
    try:
        choice = int(choice)
        if choice >= 1 and choice <= 3:
            break
    except:
        continue

print choice
```

Result :

```
Please select input menu :
Enter 1> Show latest 100 data
Enter 2> Show latest 1000 data
Enter 3> Show all data
Your choice (Input number 1 to 3) ? -1

Please select input menu :
Enter 1> Show latest 100 data
Enter 2> Show latest 1000 data
Enter 3> Show all data
Your choice (Input number 1 to 3) ? 0

Please select input menu :
Enter 1> Show latest 100 data
Enter 2> Show latest 1000 data
Enter 3> Show all data
Your choice (Input number 1 to 3) ? 5

Please select input menu :
Enter 1> Show latest 100 data
Enter 2> Show latest 1000 data
Enter 3> Show all data
Your choice (Input number 1 to 3) ? 4

Please select input menu :
Enter 1> Show latest 100 data
Enter 2> Show latest 1000 data
Enter 3> Show all data
Your choice (Input number 1 to 3) ? 3
3

Process finished with exit code 0
```